# overriding equals method in AnyRef class not working

Tags: scala

I was trying to see if equals method can be over-written in the Car (AnyRef) class. It is not working. can someone point out what is the mistake in equals method please?

```
class Car(name:String, price:Float) {

  override def equals(that:Any):Boolean = {
    val thatCar = that.asInstanceOf[Car]
    name == thatCar.name
  }
}
val aCar1 = new Car("Honda", 1000)
val aCar2 = new Car("Honda", 1000)
aCar1==aCar2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want.

```
class Car(val name:String, val price:Float){
  override def equals(that:Any):Boolean = that match {
    case x: Car => name == x.name
    case _ => false
  }
}

val aCar1 = new Car("Honda", 1000)
val aCar2 = new Car("Honda", 2100)
val aCar3 = new Car("Dodge", 3300)
aCar1==aCar2    // res0: Boolean = true
aCar1==aCar3    // res1: Boolean = false
aCar1=="Honda"  // res2: Boolean = false
```

Note that you can't access a `Car.name` constructor parameter unless it is declared as a `val`, otherwise it is private to the instance.

Answer (score 0):

@jwvh already gave a great answer.  Just wanted to add that you could also use `case class`:

```
case class Car(name: String, price: Float) {
  override def equals(that: Any): Boolean = that match {
    case x: Car => name == x.name
    case _ => false
  }
}

val car1 = Car("Honda", 8000)
val car2 = Car("Audi", 9000)
val car3 = Car("Honda", 7500)

car1 == car2  // false
car1 == car3  // true
```